# microsoft access Field must be blank or have a value that is a specific length

Tags: ms-access

I have a field on a form and I need the user to leave it blank or enter a value that is a specific length (20 characters).  Does anyone have code that may solve this need?

I have tried:

```
(Len([SIM / ENGRV]) = 20) or (isnull([SIM / ENGRV])) or ([SIM / ENGRV]="")
```

Comment: Tried that where and what happens - error message, wrong result, nothing? Have you tried Validation Rule property of textbox?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the control (field) name in the form is Text1.

So you can use this code in the before update event .

Of course, the code can be much shorter,

But I think that's the clearest way to understand the logic.

```
Private Sub Text1_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim varTmp As Variant
   ' first check if [ENGRV] > 0 to avoid devision by zero error
If Not IsNumeric([ENGRV]) And [ENGRV] = 0 Then
  Text1.Undo
  Cancel = True
Else
' now avoid [SIM] is null error
    If Nz([SIM], "") = "" Then
        Text1.Undo
        Cancel = True
    Else
       varTmp = [SIM] / [ENGRV]
      ' now we know that varTmp is somthing and not empty then check the length
         If Len(Trim(str(varTmp))) <= 20 Then
            Text1.Undo
            Cancel = True
         End If
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can do that at the table level. Set the *Validation Rule* of the field to:

```
Len([SIM / ENGRV])=20 Or [SIM / ENGRV] Is Null
```